# Checking for string contents? string Length Vs Empty String

Tags: string, optimization, language-agnostic, compiler-construction

Which is more efficient for the compiler and the best practice for checking whether a string is blank?

1. Checking whether the length of the string == 0
2. Checking whether the string is empty (strVar == "")

Also, does the answer depend on language?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it depends on language, since string storage differs between languages.

- Pascal-type strings: `Length = 0`.
- C-style strings: `[0] == 0`.
- .NET: `.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Etc.

Comment: I think the OP was asking about blank strings validation, not nullity, so when you already know that the string is not null, using IsNullOrEmpty is just another unnecessary check. So the OP's question is what takes more performance, myString.Length > 0 or myString != "". Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230/checking-for-string-contents-string-length-vs-empty-string/2306659#2306659

Answer (score 19):

In languages that use C-style (null-terminated) strings, comparing to `""` will be faster.  That's an O(1) operation, while taking the length of a C-style string is O(n).

In languages that store length as part of the string object (C#, Java, ...) checking the length is also O(1).  In this case, directly checking the length is faster, because it avoids the overhead of constructing the new empty string.

Comment: In C#, if you compare to string.Empty then you're you're comparing against an already constructed string. Then it's O(1) as well.

Answer (score 3):

> In languages that use C-style (null-terminated) strings, comparing to "" will be faster

Actually, it may be better to check if the first char in the string is '\0':

```
char *mystring;
/* do something with the string */
if ((mystring != NULL) && (mystring[0] == '\0')) {
    /* the string is empty */
}
```

In Perl there's a third option, that the string is undefined.  This is a bit different from a NULL pointer in C, if only because you don't get a segmentation fault for accessing an undefined string.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty( nystr );
```

strings can be null, so .Length sometimes throws a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 2):

For C strings,

```
if (s[0] == 0)
```

will be faster than either

```
if (strlen(s) == 0)
```

or

```
if (strcmp(s, "") == 0)
```

because you will avoid the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 2):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty()` only works on .net 2.0 and above, for .net 1/1.1, I tend to use:

```
if (inputString == null || inputString == String.Empty)
{
    // String is null or empty, do something clever here. Or just expload.
}
```

I use String.Empty as opposed to "" because "" will create an object, whereas String.Empty wont - I know its something small and trivial, but id still rather not create objects when I dont need them! ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx))

Comment: I would be really surprised if "" actually results in an instantiation inside of the C# compiler.

Comment: Use 'inputString.Length == 0', rather than 'inputString == String.Empty' for better performance

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.6, the String class has a new method [isEmpty] [1](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

There is also the Jakarta commons library, which has the [isBlank] [2](http://web.archive.org/web/20100802010006/http://commons.apache.org:80/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) method. Blank is defined as a string that contains only whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is .NET:

If you want to validate your string against nullity as well use IsNullOrEmpty, if you know already that your string is not null, for example when checking TextBox.Text etc., do not use IsNullOrEmpty, and then comes in your question.
So for my opinion String.Length is less perfomance than string comparison.

I event tested it (I also tested with C#, same result):

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim myString = ""


    Dim a, b, c, d As Long

    Console.WriteLine("Way 1...")

    a = Now.Ticks
    For index = 0 To 10000000
      Dim isEmpty = myString = ""
    Next
    b = Now.Ticks

    Console.WriteLine("Way 2...")

    c = Now.Ticks
    For index = 0 To 10000000
      Dim isEmpty = myString.Length = 0
    Next
    d = Now.Ticks

    Dim way1 = b - a, way2 = d - c

    Console.WriteLine("way 1 took {0} ticks", way1)
    Console.WriteLine("way 2 took {0} ticks", way2)
    Console.WriteLine("way 1 took {0} ticks more than way 2", way1 - way2)
    Console.Read()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Result:

```
Way 1...
Way 2...
way 1 took 624001 ticks
way 2 took 468001 ticks
way 1 took 156000 ticks more than way 2
```

Which means comparison takes way more than string length check.

Comment: However, in .Net you can avoid the explicit string comparison by comparing against string.Empty rather than the empty string (""). That should make it a O(1) operation.

Comment: I think that string.Empty is just the same literal as "", I really don't get the difference.

Comment: string.Empty is an instance of the string class whose value is "". However the string overload for Equals and (==) will do a reference comparison before it does a character for character comparison. If the references are equal than the character comparison is skipped. So comparing a value that is string.Empty to string.Empty will be significantly faster than comparing it to "" which will generate a new string object and set its initial value to "". They're not the same.

Answer (score 1):

After I read this thread, I conducted a little experiment, which yielded two distinct, and interesting, findings.

Consider the following.

```
strInstallString    "1" string
```

The above is copied from the locals window of the Visual Studio debugger. The same value is used in all three of the following examples.

**if ( strInstallString == "" ) === if ( strInstallString == string.Empty )**

Following is the code displayed in the disassembly window of the Visual Studio 2013 debugger for these two fundamentally identical cases.

```
if ( strInstallString == "" )
003126FB  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[31B2184h]
00312701  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-50h]
00312704  call        59DEC0B0            ; On return, EAX = 0x00000000.
00312709  mov         dword ptr [ebp-9Ch],eax
0031270F  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-9Ch],0
00312716  sete        al
00312719  movzx       eax,al
0031271C  mov         dword ptr [ebp-64h],eax
0031271F  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-64h],0
00312723  jne         00312750

if ( strInstallString == string.Empty )
00452443  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[3282184h]
00452449  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-50h]
0045244C  call        59DEC0B0        ; On return, EAX = 0x00000000.
00452451  mov         dword ptr [ebp-9Ch],eax
00452457  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-9Ch],0
0045245E  sete        al
00452461  movzx       eax,al
00452464  mov         dword ptr [ebp-64h],eax
00452467  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-64h],0
0045246B  jne         00452498
```

**if ( strInstallString == string.Empty ) Isn't Significantly Different**

```
if ( strInstallString.Length == 0 )
003E284B  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-50h]
003E284E  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx
003E2850  call        5ACBC87E        ; On return, EAX = 0x00000001.
003E2855  mov         dword ptr [ebp-9Ch],eax
003E285B  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-9Ch],0
003E2862  setne       al
003E2865  movzx       eax,al
003E2868  mov         dword ptr [ebp-64h],eax
003E286B  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-64h],0
003E286F  jne         003E289C
```

From the above machine code listings, generated by the NGEN module of the .NET Framework, version 4.5, I draw the following conclusions.

1. Testing for equality against the empty string literal and the static string.Empty property on the System.string class are, for all practical purposes, identical. The only difference between the two code snippets is the source of the first move instruction, and both are offsets relative to ds, implying that both refer to baked-in constants.
2. Testing for equality against the empty string, as either a literal or the string.Empty property, sets up a two-argument function call, which indicates *inequality* by returning zero. I base this conclusion on other tests that I performed a couple of months ago, in which I followed some of my own code across the managed/unmanaged divide and back. In all cases, any call that required two or more arguments put the first argument in register ECX, and and the second in register EDX. I don't recall how subsequent arguments were passed. Nevertheless, the call setup looked more like __fastcall than __stdcall. Likewise, the expected return values always showed up in register EAX, which is almost universal.
3. Testing the length of the string sets up a one-argument function call, which returns 1 (in register EAX), which happens to be the length of the string being tested.
4. Given that the immediately visible machine code is almost identical, the only reason that I can imagine that would account for the better performance of the string equality over the sting length reported by **Shinny** is that the two-argument function that performs the comparison is significantly better optimized than the one-argument function that reads the length off the string instance.

**Conclusion**

As a matter of principle, I avoid comparing against the empty string as a literal, because the empty string literal can appear ambiguous in source code. To that end, my .NET helper classes have long defined the empty string as a constant. Though I use **string.Empty** for direct, inline comparisons, the constant earns its keep for defining other constants whose value is the empty string, because a constant cannot be assigned **string.Empty** as its value.

This exercise settles, once and for all, any concern I might have about the cost, if any, of comparing against either **string.Empty** or the constant defined by my helper classes.

However, it also raises a puzzling question to replace it; why is comparing against **string.Empty** more efficient than testing the length of the string? Or is the test used by Shinny invalidated because by the way the loop is implemented? (I find that hard to believe, but, then again, I've been fooled before, as I'm sure you have, too!)

I have long assumed that **system.string** objects were counted strings, fundamentally similar to the long established Basic String (BSTR) that we have long known from COM.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, IMO the best way to determine is the IsNullOrEmpty() method of the string class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.

Update: I assumed .Net, in other languages, this might be different.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, directly checking the length is faster, because it avoids the overhead of constructing the new empty string.

@DerekPark: That's not always true. "" is a string literal so, in Java, it will almost certainly already be interned.

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan

> Actually, it may be better to check if the first char in the string is '\0':

I almost mentioned that, but ended up leaving it out, since calling `strcmp()` with the empty string and directly checking the first character in the string are both O(1).  You basically just pay for an extra function call, which is pretty cheap.  If you *really* need the absolute best speed, though, definitely go with a direct first-char-to-0 comparison.

Honestly, I always use `strlen() == 0`, because I have *never* written a program where this was actually a measurable performance issue, and I think that's the most readable way to express the check.

Answer (score 0):

Again, without knowing the language, it's impossible to tell.

However, I recommend that you choose the technique that makes the most sense to the maintenance programmer that follows and will have to maintain your work.

I'd recommend writing a function that explicitly does what you want, such as

```
#define IS_EMPTY(s) ((s)[0]==0)
```

or comparable.  Now there's no doubt at is you're checking.

Answer (score 0):

If strings in a language have an internal length property, checking the length is faster because it is an integer comparison of the property value with zero. However, when strings have no such property, the length must be determined the moment you want to test for it, and this is very fast for a string that actually has length zero, but can take a very long time if the string is huge, which you cannot know in advance, because if you knew it had size zero, why do you need to check that at all?

If a strings don't store their lengths internally, comparing against an empty string is usually faster, as even if that means that the two strings will be compared character by character, this loop terminates after the very first iteration for sure, so the time is linear (O(1)) and does not depend on string length. However, even if strings do have an internal length property, comparing them to an empty string may be as fast as checking that property as in that case most implementations will do just that: They first compare lengths and if not the same, they skip comparing characters entirely as if not even the lengths match, the strings cannot be equal to begin with. Yet if the lengths do match, they usually check for the special case 0 and again skip the character comparison loop.

And if a language does offer an explicit way to check if a string is empty, always use that, since no matter which way is faster, that is the way this check is using internally. E.g. to check for an empty string in a shell script, you could use 
`[ "$var" = "" ]` 
which would be string comparison. Or you could use 
`[ ${#var} -eq 0 ]` 
which uses string length comparison. Yet the most efficient way is in fact 
`[ -z "$var" ]` 
as the `-z` operation only exists for exactly this purpose.

C is special in that regard, as the string internals are exposed (strings are not encapsulated objects in C) and while C strings don't have a length property and their length must be determined each time needed, it is very easy to check if a C string is empty by just checking if it's first character is NUL, as NUL is always the last character in a C string, so nothing can beat:

```
char * string = ...;
if (!*string) { /* empty */ }
```

(note that in C `*string` is the same as `string[0]`, `!x` is the same as `x == 0`, and `0` is the same `'\0'`, so you could have written `string[0] == '\0'` but for the compiler that's exactly the same as what I've written above)