# Which is more efficient, "data.Length==0" or "data==string.Empty"?

Tags: c#, string, performance

I want to check whether or not a variable string `data` contain empty string.

Which is more efficient, `data.Length==0` or `data==string.Empty`?

I forgot to say, the `data` has been checked and it is guaranteed to be not `null`.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Care more about your algorithm complexity...

Comment: It just doesn't matter. The difference, if any, will never be recognizable.

Comment: Hmm, didn't expect it to be so hard to find a duplicate of this one.

Comment: I want to find the best practice even for a not-so-significant improvement.

Comment: @BoltClock: Because it's an interesting question...

Comment: @xport: The best practice in this case is to write what is clearer to the reader of the code. Therefore, I'd use data==string.Empty. But that has NOTHING to do with performance...

Comment: @xport: Are you sure you want to waste your time like this?

Comment: @xport the " best practice " here is to find the things that *actually* impact performance, and fix *them*, rather than obsessing on details that don't.

Comment: I would worry more about readability here than efficiency.  They likely are both going to perform the same.

Comment: Thank all, I will use `data.Length==0` because it runs faster.

Comment: It may run faster, but it is less readable

Comment: @Chris: Readability issue for this example is not so significant I think. :-)

Comment: I found the duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1494071/397524)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Test results for 100 million iterations:

```
Equality operator ==:   796 ms 
string.Equals:          811 ms 
string.IsNullOrEmpty:   312 ms 
Length:                 140 ms  [fastest]
Instance Equals:       1077 ms
```

[source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/empty-string)

Comment: I guessed that `Length` will be the fastest and I was right:) Nice link, btw:)

Comment: That seems extremely slow for any of the examples, I wonder if those tests were accomplished with a Pentium I processor.

Comment: @jlafay - Quote from the site - `I ran these if statements through 100 million iterations each. `

Comment: @peer: how reliable is this result?

Comment: For 100 million iterations, it seems ok. Length will just access a int in the string class. That is why it is so fast. Which operation you use, depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @peer: This is just one test result. If you're doubtful, run your own tests.

Comment: @Petar, ok gotcha. I apparent glossed over that statement :) That makes a LOT more sense! I wonder if the OP will be doing 100 million iterations as well.

Comment: Btw, I would prefer string.IsNullOrEmpty() over anything. It may be the second slowest (not too shabby) but it is the safest when considering bugs.

Comment: Remember that when you're checking the length, the string **can still be `null`**. You need to explicitly check for that first. That's why `IsNullOrEmpty` is probably a better choice, at least with readability in mind. Not to mention once you get down into this level of micro-benchmarking, a `null` check will not be completely insignificant.

Comment: I'm also quite leery of "performance" tests where it is not explicitly specified that the code was compiled *and* run with optimizations enabled...

Comment: I really believe that if you were using `string.Empty` and not `""`, the times would be faster. With `""` it creates new instance of string every iteration.

Comment: @peer: How did you make the test? I am interested to do it for other cases. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(data)` rather

Answer (score 2):

I will choose the third one, it is less bug prone:

`String.IsNullOrEmpty(data)`

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you should use the [String.isNullOrEmpty method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) to check for nulls as well.

Answer (score 2):

Neither check will be your bottleneck. However, if you opt for the first, you could run into a `NullReferenceException` if the string is null. You would not have that problem with the second.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, `data.Length == 0` is more efficient because it is simply comparing two integer values, whereas `data == String.Empty` is comparing strings (although very short ones).

However, there are a number of optimizations that the compiler or framework can potential make to minimize or eliminate any difference. This makes it hard to make absolute statements without running your own timing tests.

In the end, I doubt the difference will be enough to notice.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` (or, if it fits your requirements, from .Net 4.0 - `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`).

If you call `s.Length` then you will get a `NullReferenceException` if the string is `null`. This means you would need to check `if(s == null || s.Length == 0)`. This will be the most effective and probably the quickest, but you might aswell use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

`s == string.Empty` would return false if the string was `null` (`null` is not the same as an empty string).

In terms of performance, don't spare any more time thinking about it. It will nearly never, never, never, never impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

As people have mentioned, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)`, or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)` introduced in the .NET 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check.