# speed test site for c# code?

Tags: c#, performance, jsperf

[Which is more efficient, "data.Length==0" or "data==string.Empty"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706821/which-is-more-efficient-data-length-0-or-data-string-empty/6706844#6706844)

in this question there was an answer which describes execution times.

For Javascript : I know there is a site called http://jsperf.com/

what about **c#** site ? is there any ?

Comment: Well, you could build your own site, and then there would be one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a site, but I recently discovered that you can create a VS 2010 performance profiling session against a single unit test. Makes it very easy to quickly test isolated pieces of functionality. It's nearly as quick as pasting your code into a website and getting results, and you can get extremely detailed results (probably far better than an online solution, due to the massive amount of analysis VS is performing against the sampled data).

FWIW, there **is** an online version of a c# IDE: http://www.coderun.com/ide/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Ultimate have performance profiling tools.